# Wait function that receives data in PHP

Tags: php, wait

Can you send me in the right direction for writing a Wait function in PHP? I'm using procedural code style.

The scenario is as following:

1. First, my webapp sends data to a server, and then it should pause
   the execution on the sending client (the webapp).
2. Second, the server receives the data and does something to that data, and it sends the processed data back to the sender of step 1 (the webapp).
3. Third, the sender of step 1 (the webap) receives the processed data from the server and checks it whether it's true.

I need guidance in writing the wait and resume function.

Comment: What you are looking for is not within the grasp of (normal) php. You might be looking for `ajax` by adding some javascript.

Comment: You're talking about AJAX requests. Read up on that. A quick start to using it right away is to use a library like jQuery.

Comment: `AJAX -->` send info to `PHP--->(process)-->` send back info to `AJAX`  no need to pause the process , you can popup loading message in `ajax` while `php` is processing once php done its will send back the info to `Ajax`, you can google `$.ajax` form for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The people here said that Ajax is needed to do this. This is true. But, it's not the only option available. Using cURL is an option too, and having CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER (which returns the value after the transfer) set it does what I needed to do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This defentely sounds like you need to use AJAX. jQuery gives you some comfortable ways to solve your Problem.

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
.done(function( data ) {
alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

This is a code example from https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/.
You might have a look at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

This AJAX function calls the script test.php with the given parameters as POST variables.
You will recieve an answer (data), which you can use in your JS afterwards. I think the done() function does exactly what you are asking for. To have some consistency between the languages you could work with JSON objects.

You cannot actually stop PHP from executing. Thats why you will use a certain file which handles your request.

Comment: well you can stop php from executing by using exit, but it's not possible to resume it again (as far as i know).